# Index 51 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 50

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, keras-layer, tf.keras

I am getting this code since I tried it for the very first time. I think I am not getting the error but it is continuously showing that index 51 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 50.

batch_size = 16
num_classes = 50

```
def generate_data(samples, target_files,  batch_size=batch_size, factor = 0.1 ):
    num_samples = len(samples)
    from sklearn.utils import shuffle
    while 1:
        for offset in range(0, num_samples, batch_size):
            batch_samples = samples[offset:offset+batch_size]
            batch_targets = target_files[offset:offset+batch_size]

            images = []
            targets = []
            for i in range(len(batch_samples)):
                batch_sample = batch_samples[i]
                batch_target = batch_targets[i]
                im = Image.open(batch_sample)
                cur_width = im.size[0]
                cur_height = im.size[1]

                
                height_fac = 113 / cur_height

                new_width = int(cur_width * height_fac)
                size = new_width, 113

                imresize = im.resize((size), Image.ANTIALIAS)  
                now_width = imresize.size[0]
                now_height = imresize.size[1]
                

                avail_x_points = list(range(0, now_width - 113 ))

             
                pick_num = int(len(avail_x_points)*factor)

                
                random_startx = sample(avail_x_points,  pick_num)

                for start in random_startx:
                    imcrop = imresize.crop((start, 0, start+113, 113))
                    images.append(np.asarray(imcrop))
                    targets.append(batch_target)

         
            X_train = np.array(images)
            y_train = np.array(targets)

            #reshape X_train for feeding in later
            X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 113, 113, 1)
            #convert to float and normalize
            X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
            X_train /= 255

            
            y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
            yield shuffle(X_train, y_train)


train_generator = generate_data(train_files, train_targets, batch_size=batch_size, factor = 0.3)
validation_generator = generate_data(validation_files, validation_targets, batch_size=batch_size, factor = 0.3)
test_generator = generate_data(test_files, test_targets, batch_size=batch_size, factor = 0.1)
```

I am getting this continuously, Please Explain the error and convey information about how to get rid of this error?

Comment: Can you add the complete logs where you get this message?

Comment: Hi Rishabh, Can you please let us know what do you intend to do with the below code snipper, `avail_x_points = list(range(0, now_width - 113 ))           
                pick_num = int(len(avail_x_points)*factor)                
                random_startx = sample(avail_x_points,  pick_num)`. Also, can I know why are you not using `Keras ImageDataGenerator` for Data Generation and Data Augmentation (Cropping in your case)? Thanks!